# keith wood's jquery countdown with server time not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery that **should** be working but isn't and I can't figure out why. It's supposed to call the remote server time (in this case, I borrowed the server time of the author's website but otherwise it's calling mind - either way both are not working) and then calculate the countdown based on the time difference.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function serverTime() {
        var time = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://keith-wood.name/serverTime.php',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (text) {
                time = new Date(text);
            },
            error: function (http, message, exc) {
                time = new Date();
            }
        });
        return time;
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#defaultCountdown").countdown({
            until: new Date("Jun 24, 2015 16:00:00 +0000"),
            serverSync: serverTime
        });
    });

});
```

And the display it to:

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
```

I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ctj90jz6/1/ with all the libraries loaded but it's not working. Any ideas why? :(

Comment: Define "not working". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: The only error I am getting, even in the jsfiddle is "$.JQPLugin is undefined".

Comment: So you didn't load all the libraries then.

Comment: That's what I'm not understanding. They should be loaded, even in the jsfiddle. The jquery.plugin.js has a reference of JQPLugin in the code but it's still showing that error..

Comment: You're running coundown before plugin.

Comment: Doh! Haha, how stupid. If you make an answer I'll accept it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was moving the plugin before the countdown in the HTML code. Thanks to Quentin.